# NoMethodError When Using Database Column Aliases in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, alias

Undefined method errors when I try to use a column alias for an aggregate (PostgreSQL)

Inside my model:

```
class B2bLoginAttempt < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name "b2b_logins"
end
```

Inside my controller:

```
    @client_ip = request.env['REMOTE_ADDR']
    @sql = "select count(id) as failed_logins FROM b2b_logins WHERE ip_address = '"+@client_ip+"'"

    f = B2bLoginAttempt.find_by_sql(@sql)
    failed_attempts = f.failed_logins.to_s
    f.destroy
```

Then I see: undefined method `failed_logins' for #<Array:0x104d08478>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error occurs because `find_by_sql` returns an array, so you need to write `f.first.failed_logins.to_s` instead of `f.failed_logins.to_s`.
Check `find_by_sql` doc [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/find_by_sql/class).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I am completely following your logic correctly, but it seems like you may be better off with this:

```
f = B2bLoginAttempt.where("ip_address = ?", @client_ip)

f.map(&:destroy)
```

You can get the actual count with `f.count`

Did I miss something?